# Format set range to specific currency format all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, format, worksheet

not sure why this isnt working, but the idea is to open all worksheets, unprotect, format cells to currency, protect again whilst enabling filters. this works for protect and unprotect but trying to format I get an error message:

> Unable to set the numberformat property of the range class

```
Sub UnProtect()

    Dim cell_to_format As Range

      ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook

      For i = 1 To Sheets.Count

         Sheets(i).UnProtect "T1T3NPM"

         With ActiveSheet

       Range("L8:L99999").Cells.NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"

        Range("O8:O99999").NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"

        Range("R8:R99999").NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"

        Range("U8:U99999").NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"

        Range("X8:X99999").NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"

        Range("AA8:AA99999").NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"

        Range("AD8:AD99999").NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"

    .Protect Password:="T1T3NPM", AllowFiltering:=True
    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End With

      Next i

End Sub
```

thanks in  advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`With ActiveSheet` should be `With Sheets(i)`.

You are unprotecting `Sheets(i)` but working with the `Activesheet` which may or may not be `Sheets(i)`

Also you need to use `Worksheets` rather than `Sheets` else you will get an error if there are chart sheets.

So change `Sheets(i)` to `Worksheets(i)`

You will also need to fully qualify the range object else it will work with the `Activesheet` and not with `Worksheets(i)`

```
With Worksheets(i)
    '~~> Notice the DOT before Range
    .Range("L8:L99999").Cells.NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Sub UnProtect()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

      With ws

          .UnProtect "T1T3NPM"

          For i = 12 To 30 Step 3

              .Range(.Cells(8, i), .Cells(99999, i)).NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"

          Next i

          .Protect Password:="T1T3NPM", AllowFiltering:=True
          .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

      End With

    Next ws

End Sub
```